# get common friends between 2 users and all mutual friends between user and common firends using neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Lets assume a,b,c and b,d,e and c,f,g, and a,e,g,h are friends .So

get mutual friends b/w a&b:

```
MATCH (me:User {username:'a'}) -[r:FRIENDS]-(mutualfriends) 
       -[r:FRIENDS]- (u:User {username:'b'}) 
RETURn mutualfriends
```

Now how to get all common friends from above  and user 'a' ?
Also can we do all this in one query ?I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Don't use `r` twice, otherwise you won't get the correct results for mutual-friends. Actually you don't need `r` at all.

you just continue to match.

```
MATCH (me:User {username:'a'})-[:FRIENDS]-(mf)-[:FRIENDS]-(u:User {username:'b'}) 
WITH distinct me, mf
MATCH (me)-[:FRIENDS]-(mmf)-[:FRIENDS]-(mf)
RETURN distinct mmf
```

Comment: How can I find out number of friends or count for each of the mmf.Currently I am getting the mmf only.For eg: if a has e,h,j as common friends with b .Then count of common friends between a and e,common friends between a and h ,count of common friends between a ans j.How can I get that?Please help.